# how to use the pop() option in array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a list which i'm pushing into an array dataList. now I another function i need to pop the contents how will i go about it. Here is the code which i'm trying.

```
var dataList = new Array;
function addTheContents(){
// .... I'm doing some ajax call and getting one list,
success : function(map) {
                console.log(map);
                dataList.push(map);
                        },
error :  function() {
                alert("error occured!!!");
            },
}

function getListData(){

 dataList.pop()..... how will i get the contents from the datalist after pushing??

}
```

Comment: make sure `dataList` holds data before doing `pop()` operation. **FYI:** pop() returns the last elements within the dataList.

Comment: Make sure `getListData` is called *after* the Ajax call succeeded. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dataList` is an array.  You can read the items from the array by iterating over the indexes of the array as in:

```
for (var i = 0; i < dataList.length; i++) {
    // do something with dataList[i]
}
```

You can read just the last item in the array:

```
var item = dataList[dataList.length - 1];
// do something with item here
```

Or, if you just want to remove and retrieve the last from the array, you can do this:

```
var item = dataList.pop();
// do something with item here
```

MDN documentation for `.pop()` here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop.  It's basically the opposite of `.push()`.

There are a zillion other operations you can carry out on an array and they are all listed here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

---

In your specific code example where you are doing an ajax call, you also need to understand that most ajax calls are asynchronous.  That means they finish some time in the future.  As such, you can't just call the ajax call and then immediately examine `dataList`.  Instead, you need to put any code that needs to reference `dataList` in the success handler for the ajax call or you need to call that code from the success handler and then pass `dataList` to it.  This is how asynchronous programming works in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print all elements from your `datalist` you can use this code.

```
$.each(dataList, function(index, val) {
    console.log(val.category);
});
```

In this code you will get `index` as key and `val` as value at that position.

but `pop()` is used to remove last element from array like.

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
fruits.pop();
```

output:- Banana,Orange,Apple